# Yii2 url route manager rules fails for multiple paths

Tags: yii2, yii2-urlmanager

I would like have all routes except the api routes to navigate to the site/index route but all /api path to be executed to the respective modules.
I have added the following route rules

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            //api module
            'api/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'api/<controller:\w+>' => 'api/<controller>',

             //all other paths
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/index',
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/' => 'site/index',
        ],
    ],
```

The following works for 2 level url routes that is

```
/users/create
/users/view
```

But when i access routes with more than 2 paths like

```
/users/create/12
/admin/uom/create/new
```

The routes are not redirrected to site/index

What else do i need to add to ensure that all routes even with more than 3 paths are executed via site/index but those with api prefix are executed via `controller/action` or `/api/controller`.

What am i missing out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for such case. But you can create custom URL rule which will match any route:

```
class FallbackUrlRule extends Component implements UrlRuleInterface {

    public $route = 'site/index';

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request) {
        return [$this->route, []];
    }

    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it in your app config:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        //api module
        'api/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        'api/<controller:\w+>' => 'api/<controller>',

         //all other paths
        [
            'class' => FallbackUrlRule::class,
            'route' => 'site/index',
        ]
    ],
],
```

Note that it will simply ignore request path and catch all requests, including these that should throw 404 error. It will also not detect parameters in path (it will ignore `12` in `/users/create/12`).